# EventAggregator and ServiceLocator Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, eventaggregator

I started working on a WPF project using Prism and MVVM, and I am trying to use the eventAggregator but, when the line below is executed an exception is raised:

```
IServiceLocator ob = ServiceLocator.Current; // This line causes a Null pointer exception
EventAggregator = ob.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>();
```

But I cant understand what I am doing wrong, maybe this is a very simple thing, but I have been struggling with this for a couple hours.

Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Where is this code executed and which Bootstrapper are you using? For example, if it's Unity, you should probably use `IUnityContainer` to resolve instances rather than `ServiceLocator`.

Comment: I wasnt using any Bootstrapper, But thank Wiktor Zychla I solved my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You lack the initialization code of your locator.

Either you use Prism (do you?) and you need to set up your bootstrapper correctly - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430868(PandP.40).aspx

Or you don't use Prism and you just set up the locator manually (in `Main` for example):

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

// register the singleton of your event aggregator
container.RegisterType<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>( new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() ); 

ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider( () => container );
```

then you can call in any place of your code

```
var eventAggregator = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>();
```

Edit: you have edited your question and you now mention Prism. You should then create a custom bootstrapper, register your types and run the bootstrapper.

```
public class CustomBootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper 
{
}
```

and call

```
var bootstrapper = new CustomBootstrapper();
bootstrapper.Run();
```

in the starting routine of your application. From what I remember, `UnityBootstrapper` registers the `IEventAggregator` as singleton so you don't have to repeat that.

Comment: Since I am new using prism I didnt know I had to initialize the Locator. Thank you very much!!