# getting error 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, mvvm, prism-4

I am Unit Testing MVVM based application that uses prism and using mocking to test view model . I am able to  call the constructor of my viewmodel class by passing mock objects of region manager and resource manager but when control goes inside constructor it fails at the following statement :

```
private EventAggregator()
        {
            this.eventAggregatorInstance = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>();
        }                                                                                 It gives error : An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll
```

Additional information: Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type IEventAggregator, key "".  Please help how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you solved your problem by adding the EventAggregator to your container.

However, I would suggest that **your ViewModel should not be using the ServiceLocator** to resolve the EventAggregator at all. The ServiceLocator is a glorified static instance that is basically an anti-pattern (see [Service Locator is an Anti-Pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)). Your ViewModel should most likely accept the EventAggregator in the constructor via dependency injection and use it from there. I don't think you should need a container to test your ViewModels. You could just construct them with their constructors and pass them any mock implementations of their dependent objects (as parameters to the constructor).

Comment: I agree whatever you are saying is Ideally correct. But what if in a non Ideal world the application is built using Service Locator and one cant pass the mock object of IeventAggregator to constructor of the view model class since in my case my class has constructor with three parameters viz. IregionManager, IresourceManager, Composition Conainer but inside the class constructor it is further calling eventAggregator . so I was forced to do this albeit without much knowledge of any other workaround.

Comment: @priya You're right, you have to do that if you have no control over the ViewModel. Is it what it is. As you can see, it's obviously awkward to test it because it isn't clear what dependencies there are until the test fails. After the test fails, you just have to go back and register the type with the container. Speaking of the container, it's also incorrect that the ViewModel takes the container in its constructor. The ViewModel shouldn't use the container to resolve dependencies because then it's just the same as  ServiceLocation (you won't know which dependencies it will need).

Answer (score -1):

Based on my understanding, the **Service Locator** gets initialized when running and initializing the **Bootstrapper**. Therefore, the exception you are issuing would be caused by not having the **Locator** initialized.

I believe the following post would be useful considering the **non-Prism** alternative taking into account that you didn't run the **Bootstrapper** on the **Unit Test** scope:

- [EventAggregator and ServiceLocator Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765435/eventaggregator-and-servicelocator-issue)

You would need to set the **EventAggregator** in the **Mock Container**, and then set the **Service Locator** service for that container:

> *(Quoted from above link)*
>
> IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
>
> // register the singleton of your event aggregator
>
> container.RegisterType( new
>   ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() );
>
> ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider( () => container );

I hope this helped you,

Regards.

Comment: No , since I am using Mefbootstraper so the above is not working, I solved my problem now after a great effort by adding the Eventaggregator to the catalog in the following manner: CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            var batch = new CompositionBatch();
            batch.AddExportedValue<Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Events.EventAggregator>(new Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Events.EventAggregator());
            container.Compose(batch);
            container.ComposeParts(this);  and this works for every type of module.